# Matching keys and values of 2 dictionaries on the fly?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking for the process to happen on the fly since it can be generalized and also efficient.

This is the code I tried. It has the basic logic. However this does not work for all inputs.

```
result=[{4:5},{4:6},{4:7}]
new=[]
new=result.copy()
print("Original",result)
for i in range(0,len(result)-1):
    for key, value in result[i].items():
        for j in range(1,len(result)):
            for key_1, value_1 in result[j].items() :
                if i!=j:
                    if key==key_1:
                        print("when key=key\n",result[i],"=",result[j])
                        dict={value:value_1}
                        new[j]=dict
                        print(new)
                        break;
                    if key==value_1:
                        print("when key=value\n",result[i],"=",result[j])
                        dict={value:key_1}
                        new[j]=dict
                        print(new)
                    if value==value_1:
                        print("when value=value\n",result[i],"=",result[j])
                        dict={key:key_1}
                        new[j]=dict
                        print(new)

                    else:
                        break;

print("\nFinal =",new)
print("\nCorrect =[{4:5},{5:6},{6:7}]" )
```

input: [{4:5},{4:6},{4:7}]
output: [{4:5},{5:6},{6:7}]

Comment: What's the expected input and output, it's not very clear from the question

Comment: {4:5} states 4 is the same as 5 and {4:6} states that 4 is the same as 6 and so on. So ultimately 5 is the same as 6. So {5:6} is the desired result from the 2 dictionaries

Comment: Please add it to the question, both expected input and output

Comment: It's given above

Comment: for a list of dictionaries and the dictionary will have one item, and each dictionary will have value one greater than key, and next dictionary will follow the same, so another output might be `[{4:5},{5:6},{6:7},{7:8},{8:9}]` @SaadhvikkaV ?